# Very elementary jquery + ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

On the click of a button, I want to capture a form's data and send it to a php page using ajax, json. Now, the alert "hello hello" comes on the click of a button ONLY WHEN I HAVE COMMENTED OUT MY AJAX PORTION.
When i include the ajax portion by un-commenting it, not only do i not get any errors but also my "hello hello" alert doesnt show up.
I find this odd. Why does it happen so?

#### Here is my ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click( function() {
        alert('hello hello');
        /* Coomenting starts here
        $.ajax({
            url: "connection.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: $('#id').val(),
                name: $('#name').val(),
                Address: $('#Address').val()
            }
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (status)
            {
                if (status.success == false)
                {
                    alert("Failure!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("Success!");
                }
            }
        });
        */
    //commenting ends here.
    //basically i just commented out the ajax portion 
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a comma after the "data" block in your ajax call.

Comment: That's simply because your uncommented code can't even compile.

Comment: First thing to learn in javascript : use a inspector/debugger. See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma after "data":

```
$.ajax({
    url: "connection.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        name: $('#name').val(),
        Address: $('#Address').val()
    }, // Missing comma!
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (status)
    {
        if (status.success == false)
        {
            alert("Failure!");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    }
});
```

As @dystroy pointed out, since your code can't compile, this malformed block will potentially prevent other code (such as a simple alert) from firing.

Comment: No problem! To help avoid errors like this while coding, I frequently use the auto-formatting of my IDE (CTRL+K+D in Visual Studio 2010...I'm sure other tools have it as well). If the auto-formatting fails, then you know it's likely there is a problem with structure/syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Check comma syntax after data parameter:

```
data: {
         id: $('#id').val(),
         name: $('#name').val(),
          Address: $('#Address').val()
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after the `data` part:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click( function() {
        alert('hello hello');
        /* Coomenting starts here
        $.ajax({
            url: "connection.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: $('#id').val(),
                name: $('#name').val(),
                Address: $('#Address').val()
            },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (status)
            {
                if (status.success == false)
                {
                    alert("Failure!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    alert("Success!");
                }
            }
        });
        */
    //commenting ends here.
    //basically i just commented out the ajax portion 
    });
    });
</script>
```